# 404 Error - Jenkins Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I have a problem when I build Jenkins with tomcat I'm using:

```
jenkins version : 2.129
tomcat version : 7.0.69
```

And these are the steps:

1. change port of tomcat
2. copy jenkins.war in tomcat/webapp
3. finally run tomcat

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with above Tomcat and Jenkins version combination and it is working fine.
changed port no in server.xml in conf folder in tomcat.
placed jankins.war in webapp dir.
started tomcat.

launched by using URL http://localhost:${PORT}/jenkins

Please let me know if you are using something specific.

Edited:-As using Java version 1.7, jenkins version lesser than 2.54 will works. above that 1.8 java version is required.

Comment: hello 
please can u tell me where exactly the folder i can changed the port

Comment: i changed the port and nothing news  i have the same ERROR

Comment: I have changed the port in server.xml file at location {Tomcat_home_dir}/conf/server.xml. Please look for section --> `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />`
replace `8080` with the port no on which you want to start. if still didn't worked check for catalina.out under log dir for error. and also first you can try to bring up only tomcat server.

Comment: can you please confirm if tomcat alone is working fine? if not the check for logs. Most of the time because of java configuration issue can be there.

Comment: MY tomcat working alone and i change the port and every think is working just jenkins

Comment: no my tomcat dont work with any version of jenkins but when i build a simple project it running normaly  just jenkins dont  work

Comment: can u give me your skype mybe is better if we speak vocal voice

Comment: as of now i am in office. Can you please check by directly launching war file using cmd `java -jar  -Dserver.port=9000 jenkins.war` and then access on URL -> `http://localhost:9000`. while doing this please check logs carefully. It may show some lock files which is creating issue. if so remove those files.

Comment: so there is nothing news can u give me you skype please